# Faked ID and Chrome dioxide

Tags: starstormers

In the 1980 story *Starstormers* by Nicholas Fisk, a minor plot point involves Tsu persuading a junkyard owner to sell them a meteorite by persuading him that her father is a VIP with the ability to approve an application to emigrate away from earth. She's an orphan, but her ident card apparently confirms the lie; there follows some explanation of how she managed to achieve this:

> 'I have on my ident card.'
>
> 'But you can't have! I mean, idents can't be tampered with, they're foolproof -'
>
> 'I didn't tamper with my ident.'
>
> 'Then how -'
>
> ' I had it made out East, two years ago, when I was young. I had it carved by hand, letter by letter, from the solid plastic. Then coded inside with chrome-dioxide particles. I don't know if you understand -'
>
> 'I do,' Ispex said, looking wonderingly at Tsu. 'Chrome-dioxide ...!' he murmured.

Chrome (or Chromium) dioxide is a real substance, used in magnetic tape, so presumably any data stored on it could be modified with the right equipment - but that sounds a lot like tampering with the ident.

Is the implication that the data was rewritten, and claiming it wasn't tampered with was a lie, is something else being implied that I'm missing, or is it an entirely throwaway line without much thought behind it?

Comment: I read the passage as indicating that rather than altering an existing ident, Tsu had one crafted to encode the false information.  It's something of a nit, in that it is still a false ident, but it's the result of painstakingly creating one "from the ground up", not altering parts of an existing one.  Presumably, this avoids any telltale markers of tampering, such as residual traces of the "old" data encoded into the ident.  Similar to the difference between simply replacing the photo on an existing item (say a passport) and crafting an entire fake passport.

Comment: Not that I am implying that either is a trivial process...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Back in the day, chrome tape was the premium stuff, and for best results needed to be recorded with "high bias" and different equalization timing -- this caused a tape deck to apply more non-signal current to the recording head in order to overcome the "resistance" of the chrome oxide particles to having their magnetic polarity and strength changed (which is how a signal is recorded to the media).

Use of chrome dioxide in the ident card likely is an anti-tampering feature, because once originally recorded, it would be quite difficult to fully erase the data so encoded without leaving traces that forensic testing would reveal.

Tsu, in this case, had her ident created from *new material*, even to the point of assembling the magnetic storage directly from chrome oxide particles, thus (as suggested in comments) producing no trace of prior information that would be a clue to tampering.  Ispex's comment merely indicates that he's impressed by the level of detail that went into making an untampered, but none the less fake ident.

Comment: So not taking a valid card and tampering with it, just creating a fake in the first place? Yes, that would fit, if a bit clumsily worded (thought that might just be to me).